# PHP: Count number of information

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I do a import of a CSV tile to a array.
The CSV file is like the following:

```
Company1, Workstation, PC1
Company1, Workstation, PC2
Company1, Server, Server1
Company2, Workstation, PC1
Company2, Server, Server1
```

what i want to do, is count how many Workstations Company1 have, How many Servers Company1 have, and so on for Company2.

I like the result to be someting like:
Company1(varible with the name):
Computers: xxx
Servers: xx

I have had a look at array_count_values, but cant seem to get it to work, so i would be grateful if any could help.

Comment: Did you try something ? Writing code will not kill you ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
// Sample input data
$arrayFromCsv = [
    ['Company1', 'Workstation', 'PC1'],
    ['Company1', 'Workstation', 'PC2'],
    ['Company1', 'Server', 'Server1'],
    ['Company2', 'Workstation', 'PC1'],
    ['Company2', 'Server', 'Server1'],
];

// Data transformation
$inventory = [];
foreach ($arrayFromCsv as $row) {
    if (!isset($inventory[$row[0]])) {
        $inventory[$row[0]] = [];
    }

    if (!isset($inventory[$row[0]][$row[1]])) {
        $inventory[$row[0]][$row[1]] = 0;
    }

    $inventory[$row[0]][$row[1]]++;
}

// To get workstation count for Company1:
$company = 'Company1';
$type = 'Workstation';

if (isset($inventory[$company][$type])) {
    echo "$company has {$inventory[$company][$type]} $type(s)";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to group them, then display them in a second loop.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/760ee50729368632784dd413b00c27b14b2e898d))

```
$array=[
    ['Company1', 'Workstation', 'PC1'],
    ['Company1', 'Workstation', 'PC2'],
    ['Company1', 'Server', 'Server1'],
    ['Company2', 'Workstation', 'PC1'],
    ['Company2', 'Server', 'Server1']
];

// group the occurrences in a 2-level array
foreach($array as $row){
    if(!isset($group[$row[0]][$row[1]])){
        $group[$row[0]][$row[1]]=1;
    }else{
        ++$group[$row[0]][$row[1]];
    }
}
// display results
foreach($group as $company=>$subarray){
    echo "\n$company:";
    foreach($subarray as $key=>$num){
        echo " $key: $num";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Company1: Workstation: 2 Server: 1
Company2: Workstation: 1 Server: 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Make an array with Company like

```
$array['Company1']['Workstation'] ++
$array['Company1']['Server'] ++
```

next

```
count( $array['Company1']['Workstation'] );
```

Simplest way I think.